# Apache don't run (xampp)

Tags: windows, apache, web-services, server, xampp

I had just downloaded xampp for try to open an Apache's server, but when i opened the xampp's application, i had tryed to start apache's server, but it didn't do nothing.
In the window on bottom there is written:
`[Apache]   Attempting to start Apache service...`,
but i can wait for hours, and it will not do nothing for all the time.
I had seen some guide, which told that the problem could be the network's port, for example some people told that i have to change the port from 80 to 8080 in the file `httpd.conf`...
I tryed this solution, but the result was the same.
Have you an idea to resolve this problem?
When i open xampp the window print this:

```
16:41:52  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
16:41:52  [main]    Windows Version:  Pro  64-bit
16:41:52  [main]    XAMPP Version: 7.1.9
16:41:52  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
16:41:52  [main]    Running with Administrator rights - good!
16:41:52  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
16:41:52  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
16:41:52  [main]    All prerequisites found
16:41:52  [main]    Initializing Modules
16:41:52  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
16:41:52  [main]    Control Panel Ready
16:41:54  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...
```

In the file `error.log` of apache i have found this message:

```
[Mon Oct 09 19:41:27.872180 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 13464:tid 492] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Oct 09 19:41:28.222182 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 13464:tid 492] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Oct 09 19:41:32.168701 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13464:tid 492] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Oct 09 19:41:32.169681 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13464:tid 492] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Mon Oct 09 19:41:32.169681 2017] [core:notice] [pid 13464:tid 492] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Oct 09 19:41:32.182394 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13464:tid 492] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 21220
Apache server shutdown initiated...
sl:warn] [pid 21220:tid 452] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Oct 09 19:41:33.053714 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 21220:tid 452] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Oct 09 19:41:33.078015 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 21220:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Oct 09 19:42:22.979035 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13464:tid 492] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Oct 09 19:42:24.981274 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 21220:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Oct 09 19:42:25.016441 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13464:tid 492] AH00430: Parent: Child process 21220 exited successfully.
```

Comment: Ir running on windows, did you get any popup from the Antivirus or Windows Firewall that you rejected?

Comment: How did you check that the http server has _not_ actually started?

Comment: Try opening a browser and typing localhost in the address bar

Comment: @arkascha because if i try to open a browser and typing localhost, the server will not respond me.

Comment: If you changed the port the http server listens on then you need to connect to that port, not the standard http port.

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone i had did it, but nothing.

Comment: @arkascha I had changed the port HTTP time ago, but now it has the normal http port

Comment: @Juan I didn't get any popup from the Antivirus or Windows Firewall, i had tryed to disable Antivirus Firewall and Windows Firewall, but i have the same problem.

Comment: Have a try starting the http server executable manually from a command line prompt. What do you see as a result?

Comment: In XAMP control window you have access to the apache error log. Does anything come out there?

Comment: @Juan yes, i have already found errors in this file, i have just published it in the question

Comment: @arkascha i have try starting http server manually by "ApacheMonitor.exe", but if i click the button for start the server, it will show me an error's window which contain the message "The request operation has failed!"

Comment: That is not the http server executable. That is the monitor. The http server itself is a system daemon, it has no "button" to click on.

Comment: @arkascha how should i start the http server manually?

Comment: As written: by starting it on the command line. The advantage of that is that you can actually see the raw output of the process as written to the standard error output. Not just something filtered and altered by a number of layers in between as usual on the MS-Windows platform.